# migrating wordpress to new host, localhost refused to connect

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to migrate my wordpress application from one machine to another and set it to be local host, however after after setting everything up, I got the error "localhost refused to connect". I am using MAMP as host, and Here are all the things I have done: 
* exporting MySQL database from my old machine as sql file
* create a new database on my new machine ( same name as the old database)
* use the sql file to import all the data
* copy all the file from the wordpress folder
* past into new machine, using the same directory name

After this, I tried to re-start my wordpress application as I how I do it on my old machine, but I can not open the page, and get "localhost refused to connect"  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Can someone give me some advise on where could go wrong? And where I can start checking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the site URI and home URI.

Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Go to your options table, search the **option_value** for your previous site URI and change to localhost (e.g. www.domain.com to localhost)